# Dash home button brings up blank window

Tags: unity-dash

I have searched everything I can think of and I haven't been able to find the answer to my particular problem so if it's here, I just searched it wrong and I apologize in advance.

I am brand new to Ubuntu so please be gentle with me. :)

Here's my issue: I installed 11.10 on my son's 5 year old computer and it works well except when he clicks the top "Dash home" button. It doesn't show anything.  It grays out everything behind it like normal but there is nothing there. It's just blank, no search option or apps button to click so he can't see what apps he has installed.

Here's another weird thing about it.  It showed up fine as I was installing and getting apps he would need, but he uses this computer at school. When we brought it in to school, that's when the problem started.  I brought it back home earlier this week, plugged it in and it showed up.  Brought it back to school, just went out there today to test it and it's blank again.  What could be the issue there?  It's possibly just a coincidence.  It surely couldn't have anything to do with the network, right?  I can't imagine why that would interfere.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Comment: I've run into the same issue with Unity 2D dash on 12.04-- I get a blank screen with a search bar, and nothing I search for seems to produce any results.