# Unity on Ubuntu 11.10 - The Dash Home button brings up the panel, but is empty

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

The dash home button brings up a panel that is greyed out, but it is totally empty.

It seems to be the very same issue as this: [Dash home button brings up blank window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79874/dash-home-button-brings-up-blank-window) which is unanswered.

`/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`
returns

```
OpenGL vendor string:   X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV370
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.11

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I've tried a `unity --reset` but that doesn't seem to work.  Unity seems to reset, but I get the following warning over and over: `cs space validation failed unity`

What should I do next to try and fix this?

Edit: 
Attempted fixes: 
I've refomatted, did not work.
I've done `apt-get remove unity` then `apt-get update` then `apt-get install unity`, did not work.

I've switched to Unity 2d and this seems to work.  How can I get regualar Unity working or atleast find the error?

Comment: Can u post a screenshot of it?

Comment: @shantanu Asker has already tried it... unity --reset

Comment: Sorry, i said reinstall unity from synaptic not reset from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

@shantanu How would I reinstall this?  I can do an `apt-get remove unity`, then `apt-get install unity`?  I did a complete reformat to make sure that it wasn't a one time thing but it's still happening.

@sanjayasanjuubuntu I need a reputation of 10 to post images on this site, but here is a link.  http://s13.postimage.org/t9m0rirxz/Screenshot.png

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity