# How to get the Dash and HUD to appear. (and stop Unity spewing error messages.)

Tags: unity, 12.04, ati, unity-dash, hud

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my wifes Dell Inspiron 1501, which uses an R300 ATI graphics chip. Neither the Dash or HUD appear when pushing the appropriate key. When I try unity --reset & in the terminal, I see that over and over it's spitting out:

```
r300: CS space validation failed. (not enough memory?) Skipping rendering.
```

This is just after starting Ubuntu with no apps open, so I find it hard to believe that just rendering the Dash / HUD is completely blowing out the VRAM. Any suggestions on getting this working?

---

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

shows

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org R300 
Project OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS480 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.2 
Not software rendered: yes
Not blacklisted: yes
GLX fbconfig: yes
GLX texture from pixmap: yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program: yes
GL fragment program: yes
GL vertex buffer object: yes
GL framebuffer object: yes
GL version is 1.4+: yes

Unity 3D supported: yes
```

All sections say "YES"

Comment: Seems to be the same error as:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/95675/unity-on-ubuntu-11-10-the-dash-home-button-brings-up-the-panel-but-is-empty
and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/79874/dash-home-button-brings-up-blank-window

Comment: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   X.Org R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RS480
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.2

All sections say "YES"

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report on launchpad/bugzilla (include if possible xorg.log, dmesg, glxinfo, lscpi and .xsession-errors)

Answer (score 1):

The Unity 2d desktop might fix this issue,

You can Access Unity 2D at the LighDM log in screen (only if you have automatic login disabled).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, tried countless things, and using Unity 2D it indeed fixed the problem.

This was on a Dell Dimension e510.  Clicking on the Dash icon did not display the Dash window, but if I typed (invisibly) 'terminal' and pressed Enter, a terminal opened.

`unity --reset` is suggested elsewhere, and this produces endless r300 errors as the initial post described.  With Unity 2D, it works fine.